# Mod_rewrite website like facebook

Tags: php, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite for the first time in order o create a website similar to facebook.

Whener I type mywebsite.com/user.name, the mod_rewrite redirects me to mywebsite.com/hotsite/index/php and there, I use a little php to get the user name from the url and get the userId from it.

Then I have the other areas like mywebsite.com/user.name/diary, mywebsite.com/user.name/contact, and so on...

This is all working well with this code in my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mywebsite

# ————————————————————————-
# > URL REWRITING
# ————————————————————————-

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/diario$ hotsite/diary.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/recados$ hotsite/messages.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/fotos$ hotsite/photos.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/videos$ hotsite/videos.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/contato$ hotsite/contact.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9._\-]+)$ hotsite/index.php [L]
```

The problem I have is with the path to the external files (css, images, backgrounds...).
Since my browser thinks I am in "website.com" I had to add "hotsite/" to all the paths. This works well for when I am at the user main page, like "mywebsite.com/user.name". However, if I go to "mywebsite.com/user.name/diary" the browser thinks I'm in another folder and then I have to add "../hotsite" in order for the paths to work.

I could make an IF in all the paths to check if I am at the index or not, but this would be very clumsy.
I could also put absolute paths in evertyhing, but since I'm developing offline with apache, this wouldn't be good either.

Any other solutions?

Thank you vey much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use the `base` tag available in HTML (put it between the `<head></head>` tags):

```
<base href="yoursiteroot" />
```

In other words, something like this:

```
<base href="/mywebsite" />
```

However, this requires that your relative links are adjusted based on the path you specify. :-)

Comment: I think that did it! I added the base tag to all my htmls execpt the index and it worked.

Thank you!